# Is this restriction map surjective?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Let $H_1$ be the set of all holomorphic bounded functions on the open unit disc $D$ and let $H_2$ be the set of all holomorphic bounded functions on $U$ where $U=D-\{\frac {-1}{2},\frac {1}{2}\}$.
Let $r:H_1\rightarrow H_2$ be defined as $r(f)=f|_U $. Then is this r is injective and surjective?
I think r is both $1-1$ and onto.
My logic is:
Using the theorem "If $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic functions on $D$ and $f=g$ on a set which has a limit point in $D$ then $f=g$ on $D$.", we can easily prove that $f|_U=g|_U\Rightarrow f=g$ on $D.$
i.e. $r$ is $1-1$.
Now I think, from the "Riemann theorem on removable singularities" it follows that for any $f\in H_2$, there exists $g\in H_1$ such that $r (g)= f$.
Is my logic correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's just fine. Note that the expression “Riemann theorem” is innapropriate. A better expression would be [“Riemann's theorem on removable singularities”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem).

Comment: Thanks ye for the response! And I have edited it accordingly...